# Hide menu when window width resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I want to eliminate the topMenu when the width of the window is wider than 479px.

This is the code, and I used .hide and **.css('display','none')** and, even .slideToggle(false), but it doesn't work. The default setting in CSS is display:none.

The slideToggle Menu appears when windows are smaller than 479px with a click event, and then, when windows are wider than 479px I need to stop that function, because I have another menu for wider windows, that appears with the same click event.

I can´t make disapear or eliminate that function in wider windows.

```
    $(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var windowSize = $(window).width(); 
    if(windowSize > 479){
        $('#topMenu2').hide();

    } 
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: CAN YOU CREATE A FIDDLE?

Comment: yep, more code would be helpful

Comment: @gaurravv5 no need to yell..

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on this, here it goes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EuMS4/

Answer (score 1):

What about CSS solution?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 479px) {
    #topMenu2 {display: none}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The problem is if a put that, the slideToggle just change the initial display. If a put display:none, the slideToggle shows at first nothing and when I click the trigger its slides and the menu appears. I need to disappear it when the window gets wider.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px)
{
    #topMenu2
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting almost the same answer as @panther. Anyway, since OP has set `display: none` by default, my answer should work "as it is", without need for any further edit in their CSS code. ;)

Comment: Thanks!! But, I still have the same problem. With display the slideToggle just change the initial display. If a put display:none, the slideToggle shows at first nothing and when I click the trigger its slides and the menu appears. I need to disappear it when the window gets wider